# Adding bags to booking after outbound flight

Tags: luggage, aer-lingus

I have a return flight booked with Aer Lingus.  When I go to "Manage Booking" I can add bags to both legs of the flight.  However, I'm unsure at the moment if I require 20 or 25kg for the inbound leg.  If I add a bag only for the outbound leg, can I add a bag for the inbound leg once I have already flown on the outbound leg?

Comment: I would say it's very likely, but better be safe by calling the airline

Comment: How much is the difference between both bags? Is it worth the hassle of adding the bag later and not simply choosing 25kg now?

Comment: @Sabine  The difference is trivial - €5 - however if it is not an issue I'd rather avoid having to pay the extra if I don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.  I have flown out and successfully added a bag to my return flight online paying the same as if I had done it before the outbound leg had flown.